# how to solve cloudera incompatible verions for different builds within cdh3

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I have the following error in the cluster:

```
2012-10-31 21:15:49,414 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Incompatible build versions: namenode BV = 318bc781117fa276ae81a3d111f5eeba0020634f; datanode BV = 217a3767c48ad11d4632e19a22897677268c40c4
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.handshake(DataNode.java:587)
```

My master has :

```
Subversion file:///data/1/tmp/nightly_2012-02-16_09-46-24_3/hadoop-0.20-0.20.2+923.195-1~maverick -r 217a3767c48ad11d4632e19a22897677268c40c4
```

And all slaves  have:

```
Subversion file:///data/1/tmp/nightly_2012-03-20_13-13-48_3/hadoop-0.20-0.20.2+923.197-1~maverick -r 318bc781117fa276ae81a3d111f5eeba0020634f
```

How can I down-grade mater to b195? 
How can I point to build number to install?

In general I have the following in the repository:

```
cat  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudera.list 
deb http://archive.cloudera.com/debian maverick-cdh3u3 contrib
deb-src http://archive.cloudera.com/debian maverick-cdh3u3 contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

For all, This is a little bit hacky but I did the following thing to have an "img" of the installation.

On on eof the machines where I have the version with build number I want, I've copied all hadoop .deb files

```
/var/cache/apt/archives/ 

hadoop-0.20_0.20.2+923.197-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
hadoop-0.20-jobtracker_0.20.2+923.197-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
hadoop-0.20-namenode_0.20.2+923.197-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
hadoop-0.20-native_0.20.2+923.197-1~maverick-cdh3_amd64.deb
hadoop-0.20-secondarynamenode_0.20.2+923.197-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
hadoop-hbase_0.90.4+49.137-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
hadoop-hbase-master_0.90.4+49.137-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
hadoop-zookeeper_3.3.4+19.3-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
hadoop-zookeeper-server_3.3.4+19.3-1~maverick-cdh3_all.deb
```

Then I simply run dpkg -i for all packages, and thus I can "install" the appropriate version